# How can I set a global click listener to grab the value from many buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, button

I have an array of buttons, which each hold a different value.
I need to add an event listener to listen for when it has been clicked.
The value of the button clicked will be pushed into a different array.

I feel like I need `forEach`, but can't quite fit it in.

```js
function placeBet() {
  var betBtn_nodelist = document.querySelectorAll('.bet_amount > button');
  var betButtonsArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(betBtn_nodelist);

  for (var i = 0; i < betButtonsArr.length; i++) {
    betButtonsArr[i];
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bet_amount">
  <button class="five" value="5">5</button>
  <button class="ten" value="10">10</button>
  <button class="fifty" value="50">50</button>
  <button class="hundred" value="100">100</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to attach a `click` event handler for every item from your `array`.

```js
result = [];
function placeBet(){
    var betBtn_nodelist = document.querySelectorAll('.bet_amount > button');
    var betButtonsArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(betBtn_nodelist);
    for (let i = 0; i < betButtonsArr.length; i++) {
       betButtonsArr[i].onclick = function(){
         result.push(this.value);
         console.log(result);
       }
    }
}
placeBet();
```

```html
<div class="bet_amount">
    <button class="five" value="5">5</button>
    <button class="ten" value="10">10</button>
    <button class="fifty" value="50">50</button>
    <button class="hundred" value="100">100</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah I see, I might need to read more about the 'this'. Not sure how it's scoped.
Will use this for now, since it's vanilla JS. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way using jquery :

```js
var values = []
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
  values.push(this.value)
  console.log(values)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<div class="bet_amount">
  <button class="five" value="5">5</button>
  <button class="ten" value="10">10</button>
  <button class="fifty" value="50">50</button>
  <button class="hundred" value="100">100</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Wasn't me that downvoted. Either way, I'm looking for a vanilla JS solution.

Comment: @Daniel you didn't specify that in your question that you are looking for a vanilla js solution, anyway consider it a possible jquery solution anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

> how can I set a global click listener to grab the value?

Yes, you have to set a **global** click listener for all buttons in only one object – `<div class="bet_amount">`. If you set one click listener for each button then it is bad for the browser perfomance.

With `e.target.nodeName == 'BUTTON'` you can recognize the click on buttons inside `"bet_amount"` class element.

```js
var result = [];

function placeBet()
{
    var betAmount = document.querySelector('.bet_amount');
    betAmount.onclick = function(e)
    {
        if(e.target.nodeName == 'BUTTON')
        {
            result.push(+e.target.value); //"+" is converting to integer
            console.log(result.join(','))
        }
    };
}
placeBet();
```

```html
<div class="bet_amount">
    <button class="five" value="5">5</button>
    <button class="ten" value="10">10</button>
    <button class="fifty" value="50">50</button>
    <button class="hundred" value="100">100</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @Daniel, if you have on your site more than one `bet_amount` element and you do not know how to write it for all them then ask me.

Comment: I changed my approach and used a for loop to listen for a click event on each button. After that I used "betAmount += +this.value;" to return an integer for easier calculating purposes. That way the clicked bet amounts also get added up together! Thanks a lot though!

Comment: @Daniel, I think you did not understand what I wrote. With my code at first you do not nead to have a loop and your listener is only on one object. It means your code is more faster. It is very important if you have more listeners on your page because each listener need computer memory and it is one extra process. Read [this article](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm) about this. And `this.value` is not an integer! It is a string. You can convert it to integer with each mathematical operation. For ex.  `this.value * 1`. Or with two strings: `"15" + "15" = 30`

Comment: @Daniel, In my case I convert the value to integer like `+e.target.value` (mathematical operation). And in your case it is `+this.value`.